# How to recreate let's encrypt certificate with public key from the past?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, pinning

So what we have is an invalid let's encrypt certificate, when we try to renew it, public key changes. Is there a way to preserve the old public key? Our clients have it implemented for SSL pinning purposes.

`certbot certificates` shows:

`Certificate Name: domain.com-0001
    Domains: domain.com api.domain.com beta-api.domain.com beta.domain.com demo.domain.com
    Expiry Date: 2018-04-16 11:58:34+00:00 (INVALID: EXPIRED, REVOKED)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com-0001/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com-0001/privkey.pem`

Renewal actually works, but it generates a new SHA256. Is it possible to preserve the old one? Please help, thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible. Which is one reason why certificate pinning is not suitable for production use.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's possible, and the solution is following:

Navigate to the new folder and run:

`sudo certbot certonly --csr /etc/letsencrypt/csr/crs-filename.pem`

This command will generate new, valid letsencrypt certificate inside that folder.

Then you have to create fullchain manually by running:

`sudo cat filename-cert.pem filename-chain.pem > filename-fullchain.pem`

The last step is pointing to that file inside Nginx config (in my case this is Nginx):

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com.conf`

Throw in following lines:

`listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /home/username/letsencrypt/filename_fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/archive/domain.com/privkey.pem
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;`

Restart Nginx by running:

`sudo service nginx restart`

This will point web server to a new certificate (full chain) while using the old private key.

An original discussion and solution were posted [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-recreate-lets-encrypt-certificate-with-public-key-from-the-past/60096).